# Remove DOM Node from a browser's document object

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

I have read in http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp that adding an element goes in two steps:
* create in document object
* add to the parent node.

But when removing, I just remove from the parent node, and don't delete in the document object. Will there be a memory leak or something if I repeat creating, adding and removing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "create in document object" phrase is misleading.

The `createElement` function is simply a *property* of the `document` object, allowing the function to exist without it having to be a global function:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
```

It's akin to what we'd call a "static factory method" in other OOP languages.

The newly created element doesn't actually sit within the DOM (and hence inside the tree of nodes below `document`) until it's added to a parent node, e.g.

```
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

Answer (score 0):

removed elements are garbage collected time after time. so you don't need to worry about memory leaks